# Como agregar elementos a un JSON externo con javascript

Tags: javascript, json

tengo este JSON esterno llamado productos.json

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Manzana",
        "precio": 1000
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Pera",
        "precio": 2000
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Laptop",
        "precio": 10000
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Manzana",
        "precio": 1000
    }
]
```

tengo mi archivo de javascript index.js y llamo al JSON de esta manera

```javascript
fetch("./productos.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>{
    console.log(data)
})
```

y quiero desde javascript agregar otro elemento más

Hay alguna manera de hacerlo? y si la hay por favor ayuda

si necesitan mas info me avisan

Comment: ¿Externo dónde? ¿Cómo accedes a él? ¿Qué entiendes aquí por *agregar*?

Comment: tengo el json por separado y lo llamo como si fuera una api, quiero agregar otro elemento como si fuera un crud

Comment: _Como si fuera una api_ ... ese JSON lo estás generando de algún lado lo hiciste a mano?

Comment: Eso es un Array. Basta usar el método [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) para añadir lo que necesites.

Comment: O sea, quieres agregar más cosas al JSON ya obtenido... Bien, ya entendemos esa parte. Ahora, dinos qué has intentado y qué problema concreto tienes en base a ese intento. Ni siquiera se sabe qué es lo que quieres agregar ni en qué parte del JSON ni de donde sacas eso que quieres agregar.

Comment: No queda claro lo que quieres: ¿leer un fichero json y modificarlo? Lo puedes hacer con node, pero desde un navegador no, tendrías que enviarlo a backend y que éste lo guardara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var json = {"id": 4, "nombre" : "Pera", "Precio" : 2000};

fetch("json/005.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>{
    data.push(json);
    console.log(data);
})
```

Defines una variable, en este caso la llamo json, y la meto un objeto.

Luego, cuando obtengo el data, le hago un `data.push(json)` y ya tienes metido en data el nuevo objeto.

El problema de lo que quieres es el siguiente:

Con js no puedes acceder en modo de escritura a los archivos. Deberías poder hacerlo bien con PHP con los métodos GET o POST; o bien con node js y las librerías `fs`.

Por tanto, reescribir el archivo que quieres es imposible a no ser que uses otras librerías.

---

**EDIT**

Si quieres que la variable json sea dinámica y le metas tu mismo los valores por el prompt, haz esto:

```
var json = {"id": prompt('Escribe el id'), "nombre" : prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta'), "Precio" : prompt('Inserta el precio de la fruta')};
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Si quieres insertar todos los valores a mano del objeto al que vas a hacer push, y que los valores numéricos tengan que ser si o si numéricos, haz lo siguiente:

```
//  Insertar el valor del ID
var id = prompt('Escribe el id');
    while(!id || isNaN(id)){
       id = prompt('Escribe el id');
    }
//  Parsear el valor del id
var id = parseInt(id);


//  Insertar el valor de la fruta
let frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
while(/\d/.test(frut)) { //mientras haya algún número
  frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
}

//  Insertar el valor del precio
var price = prompt('Escribe el valor de '+frut);
    while(!price || isNaN(price)){
        price =  prompt('Escribe el valor de '+frut);
    }

//  Parsear el valor del precio
var price = parseInt(price);

//  Insertar los valores dentro del objeto
var obj = {"id": id, "nombre" : frut, "Precio" : price};


//  Recorrer el archivo y leerlo
fetch("json/001.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>{
    //  Hacer un push del objeto dentro del array
    data.push(obj);
    console.log(data);
})
```

Con el while(!var || isNaN(var)){...} lo que haces es comprobar, primero que exista, y segundo, que sea un valor numérico. como el prompt te lo devuelve en modo texto, hace falta pasarlo a un entorno numérico.

En cambio, no existe ninguna fruta (que yo sepa) con números en su nombre, por tanto, si en la variable `frut` detecta un número dentro, retornará en bucle hasta que se escriba correctamente.

Eso se hace con parseInt(var)

---

**EDIT 3**

También podemos hacer que añadas automáticamente el valor del id, de forma que no se pueda repetir, en este caso, dinámicamente con un botón:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="js/001.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>PULSAME</label>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="addValue()">+</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```javascript
function addValue(){
    //  Recorrer el archivo y leerlo
    fetch("json/001.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>{
        var lth = data.length; //Obtenemos de data el length, y lo metemos en la variable lth
        var obj = defineObj(lth+1); //Metemos en la variable obj el valor que obtengamos de la funcion defineObj, a la cual le pasamos como parametro lth + 1
        // Pasamos lth + 1 ya que si queremos que el id no sea repetido, debemos añadirle uno mas. 
    data.push(obj); //  Hacer un push del objeto dentro del array
    console.log(data);
    })
}

function defineObj(lth){
    var id = lth; // esto es totalmente innecesario, pero es por mi propia comodidad

    let frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
            while(/\d/.test(frut)) { //mientras haya algún número
            frut = prompt('Escribe el nombre de la fruta');
            }
    
    var price = prompt('Escribe el valor de '+frut);
            while(!price || isNaN(price)){
                var price = prompt('Escribe el valor de '+frut);
            }
    
    var price = parseInt(price);
    var id = parseInt(id);

    var obj = {"id": id, "nombre" : frut, "Precio" : price};
    
    return obj; // retornamos la variable obj como parametro de la funcion, la cual recogera el obj de la linea 7
}
```

Ahora, si lograses con `nodejs` o `php` el sobreescribir el documento, tendrías un botón dinámico y funcional que te permitiría añadir tantos `objetos` nuevos quieras a tu `array` en el `JSON`

(Y ya no me veo capaz de mejorarlo)

Comment: GRACIAS, es justo lo que necesitaba lo explicaste muy bien

Comment: Me alegro, me lo pasé muy bien haciéndolo =3